# Linq: multiple sub joins or sub-queries

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-membership, subquery, left-join, membership-provider

I am pretty sure I can get the results I want from a single Linq statement, I am just not able to find it by myself! This is what I have so far:

```
var query = from uir in Aspnet_UsersInRoles
        join r in Aspnet_Roles
        on uir.RoleId equals r.RoleId 
        select new
        {
            UserId = uir.UserId,
            RoleName = r.RoleName
        };

var query2 = from q in query
        group q by q.UserId into roles
        select new 
        {
            UserId = roles.Key,
            Roles = roles.Distinct()
        };

var query3 = from u in Aspnet_Users
        join q in query2
        on u.UserId equals q.UserId
        select new
        {
            UserId = u.UserId,
            UserName = u.UserName,
            Roles = q.Roles
        };
```

Expected Results:
[image: Expected Results]

and that is not even correct: I don't really need to have UserId in the 'Roles' list/IEnumerable, just a list of the RoleName(s) for each UserId.

I am using asp.net membership sql tables and basically I want to get a listing of users including their Roles.

- Each user might have multiple roles.
- Users might have no Role at all (and should still show up on results)

Can you please help me or point me in the right direction on how to get the same results from a single Linq statement?

PS. Yes, I am a Linq newbie and a SQL veteran, that might be obscuring my thoughts.

**EDIT**

Ok, I think I am getting to it:

```
var q = from u in Aspnet_Users
    from up in UserProfiles.Where( _up => _up.UserId == u.UserId ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from uir in Aspnet_UsersInRoles.Where( _uir => _uir.UserId == u.UserId ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from r in Aspnet_Roles.Where( _r => _r.RoleId == uir.RoleId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    group r.RoleName by new     {
                                u.UserId, 
                                u.UserName, 
                                up.FirstName, 
                                up.LastName, 
                                u.LastActivityDate
                                } into g
    select new 
    {
        userID = g.Key.UserId,
        firstName = g.Key.FirstName,
        lastName = g.Key.LastName,
        userName = g.Key.UserName,          
        lastActivityDate = g.Key.LastActivityDate,
        roles = g.Distinct()
    };
```

What do you think? 
(I added info from my own UserProfiles table, 1:1 relation w/ Aspnet_Users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is equivalent.

```
var query = from userRole in Aspnet_UsersInRoles
            join role in Aspnet_Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.RoleId 
            group role.RoleName by userRole.UserId into roles
            join user in Aspnet_Users on roles.Key equals user.UserId
            select new
            {
                user.UserId,
                user.UserName,
                Roles = roles.Distinct(),
            };
```

See if this works out.

Comment: I get: "The name 'userRole' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'."

Comment: If I swap the expressions I get: "The name 'user' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'."

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake, I was trying to keep it readable and changed things around where I probably shouldn't have.  The groupby took `userRole` out of scope.

Comment: I missed your point about the queries you were merging were wrong, I corrected that.  You just wanted to group role names only so now it does.